# Populate a list of Sunday's dates and ignore the Sundays in an exception list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I'm working on a sheet which I have to populate with Sunday dates, and make sure that dates from an exception list aren't present in my final list

Goal: to have the list of dates of only working Sundays

here is a preview

```
working days    .........                  Vacation days  
07/01/2012         ............               04/02/2012  
14/01/2012         ............               11/02/2012  
21/01/2012  
28/01/2012{{                  
18/02/2012  
25/02/2012  
03/03/2012  
10/03/2012  
17/03/2012  
24/03/2012  
31/03/2012
```

So far I populated the list in column A with this :

```
A1 =2012  
A3 =DATE(A1;1;1)+7-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1;1;1))  
A4 =IF(YEAR(A3+7)=$A$1;A3+7;"")
```

How can I improve this so it can ignore vacation dates when listing working Sundays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those dates you listed appear to be **Saturdays** but assuming you want **Sundays** as stated then in **Excel 2010** you can use this formula in A3

`=WORKDAY.INTL(DATE(A$1;1;0);1;"1111110";C$2:C$10)`

Assuming vacation dates listed in **C2:C10**

then this formula in A4 copied down to A55

`=IF(A3="";"";IF(YEAR(WORKDAY.INTL(A3;1;"1111110";C$2:C$10))=A$1;WORKDAY.INTL(A3;1;"1111110";C$2:C$10);""))`

In Excel 2007 you can use these formulas for A3 and A4 copied down respectively:

`=DATE(A1;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1;1;7))+MIN(IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$10;DATE(A1;1;1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1;1;7))+7*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})=0;{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}))*7`

and

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C$10;A3+7*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})=0;IF(YEAR(A3+7*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9})=A$1;A3+7*{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}));1);"")`

latter formulas assume you never have more than 8 consecutive Sunday vacactions

Comment: That was all i need thanks so much... it's working like a charm. both formulas on 2007 and excel 2010 tested. i confirm what u said on 2007 it doesn't work for more than 8 consecutive sunday vacations i tried to vote up for your answer but i don't have enougn reputation points thanks again

Comment: You should be able to "accept" my answer.....If you want more than 8 consecutive Sundays you can just extend the {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9} part to be one more than you need as maximum